# How to distinguish floor, walls and celling in hittest of WebXR

Tags: augmented-reality, hittest, webxr

Unfortunately there is no documentation for Augmented Reality (ARButton) feature of Three.JS. In [the example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=webxr#webxr_ar_hittest) objects are not being placed distinguishing floor or wall. Can you guide how to correct the sizing of added object and rotation based on wall and floor. This is being done by ARCore as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/webxr/hello-webxr) but unable to do this in Three.JS example.